# Google cloud VM instance not respoding?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, root

Google cloud vm instance not responding after restart its just shows like this. [Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfU6F.png).

[image]

Please help me to fix this there is alot of things inside this instance. Thanks

Comment: Need serial console logs or instance logs. File system might be corrupted after reboot.

Comment: @Rahul Raj just as a kind reminder take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers , so, if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the issue in the serial console, you can follow [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) to enable serial console access for a specific instance, once the access is enabled, follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) to connect to the serial port.

You can try the following troubleshoot steps:

1. Reboot the instance

Instances that use the most recent versions of [Public images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) can automatically resize their partitions and file systems after a system reboot.

2. Check available space

To check space (disk usage) just run the command on terminal

```
    df -h
```

Will list the disk usage on unix and get the output like

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda5        28G   15G   12G  58% /
```

If the root (mounted on /) usage is 100%, you need to clean the tmp directory or restart the machine to make some space on the root.

3. Detach disk and attach it to a new instance

You can detach the boot disk and then attach that disk as a secondary disk on a new instance using the following gcloud commands:

```
gcloud compute instances delete $PROB_INSTANCE \
    --keep-disks=boot 

gcloud compute instances create new-instance \
    --disk name=$BOOT_DISK,boot=yes,auto-delete=no 

gcloud compute ssh new-instance
```

Or you can also do the same using the console following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk).

Comment: Hey Unfortunately it did not help me i had to delete my Vm and create new one,Thanks. @JoseLuisDelgadillo